# Sorting HashMap by key and value accepting null instances

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have a HashMap that contains a list of users and the key is the id of the team that this user participates. The set of keys looks like this:

```
[59b83da60b616d17065a993a, null, 59b84145cb49632609e03811, 59a82440cc32316561d803ce, 59c109aa20fe7b48f3832eef, 59a74647cc32316561d7be21, 59c5013b20fe7b48f3871c83]
```

Taking into consideration that every team has an ID and a name, I would like to know how can I sort this HashMap by the corresponding names if these IDs and keeping the field `null` in the first position of the HashMap.

I have a list of teams where I could easily check what is the name of a team with the ID "1" using the method `getName(String id)`. But my difficulty is to deal with the HashMap.

Comment: HashMaps are designed for quick lookups.  They are not designed to be sorted.  You will need to select a different data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your want to sort your map, you should not use `HashMap`, use some `SortedMap` like `TreeMap` instead. You can typically initialize such maps with a comparator to specify the sorting order. Something like:

```
Map<String, Team> teams = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```